# perform animation "pulse", to an icon using css

Tags: css

How about friends, I'm new to the topic of CSS. I am trying to perform a **pulse** effect as you can see in this link:

[image]

https://codepen.io/seansean11/pen/dhwzj

```
  .container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: #fff;
  }

  .pulse-button {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: light;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #5a99d4;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, .5);
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
  }
  .pulse-button:hover {
    -webkit-animation: none;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
      @include transform(scale(.9));
    }
    70% {
      @include transform(scale(1));
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
    }
      100% {
      @include transform(scale(.9));
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
    }
  }
```

I would like my **menu icon**(icon next to word "Home") to have a similar animation. Maybe a circle below the icon that tries to make the animation "pulse".

[image]

Can you guide me a little please? I do not know how to put a background to the icon.

I share the source code that I am doing, if you want to edit something, you must modify the **app/app.css** file, to see in real time.

[image]

thank you very much

https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-level-side-menu-k3exgi?file=app/app.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the styles to this selector "ion-header button[ion-button].bar-buttons"

```
ion-header button[ion-button].bar-buttons {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5a99d4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(90, 153, 212, 0.5);
  animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}
ion-header button[ion-button].bar-buttons:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
   transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(90, 153, 212, 0);
  }
    100% {
     transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(90, 153, 212, 0);
  }
}
```